# Writing to multiple files without duplicating code Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have this code to write to a file when I add a user to an array list. The code works fine:

```
public void writeToFile(String content)
    {
        try {
            File file = new File("H:/JavaWorkspace/TradingPlatformProject/User_Report.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content + "\n" );

            bw.close();
            logger.info("Recorded to User Activity file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I want to write to a separate file when a user does something differently (say, request a permission upgrade). Is there any way I can write to a new file "UserRequests.txt" without duplicating this code?

Comment: Perhaps simply add in the file name or operation as a parameter?

Answer (score 7):

Why not make the method more general?

```
  public void writeToFile(String content, String fileName, String path)
  {
        try {
            File file = new File(path + fileName);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content + "\n" );

            bw.close();
            logger.info("Recorded to User Activity file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

Then you could use the method for writing all kinds of files :3

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just use a 2nd argument, as in the following.
Moreover, you should close your Writers in a finally block. That way, you would be sure that the Writers are closed even if a exception occurred while writing.

```
public void writeToFile(String content, String path)
{
    FileWriter fw
    BufferedWriter bw 
    try {
        File file = new File(path);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content + "\n" );

        bw.close();
        logger.info("Recorded to User Activity file");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just pass in the file you want to write to:

```
public void writeToFile(String content, String filename){
```

And then:

```
File file = new File("H:/JavaWorkspace/TradingPlatformProject/"+filename);
```